# How to add validation to taginput element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my `Vue.js` application I use [taginput](https://buefy.github.io/documentation/taginput) element of `Buefy` library. I want to add validation to input. Make aviable to enter only numbers, no letters. I tried next code but unfortunatly it didn't work. How to fix this problem?

```
<b-taginput v-model="tags" type="is-warning" @keypress='onlyNumberValidation'>
</b-taginput>

onlyNumberValidation ($event) {
    let keyCode = ($event.keyCode ? $event.keyCode : $event.which)
    if ((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) && keyCode !== 46) {
        $event.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in simple way by checking the input by using the default feature as shown below
Template

```
<div id="app" class="container">

    <section>
        <b-field label="Tags with 3 characters">
            <b-taginput
v-model="tags"

:before-adding="beforeAdding">
            </b-taginput>
        </b-field>
    </section>

</div>
```

Script

```
beforeAdding(tag) {
            return tag.match(/^\d+$/);
        },
```

Below is the codepen link as a demo
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wNooaY?editors=1010

Comment: Hello! I have several questions. Right now I use `:before-adding` attribure and my `beforeAdding` function has next code: `beforeAdding (tag) {return tag.length === this.inputMaxLength}` How I can correctly add your code? Is it realy impossible to make disable to write letters? This your solution make aviable to add letters in input. It's not what I want exactly.

Comment: You may change return statement accordingly using && condition as -> return tag.match(/^\d+$/) && tag.length === this.inputMaxLength;